# How do I extract keyword from webpage using PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, curl, domdocument

Here is a same of code I have extracted from a webpage...

```
        <div class="user-details-narrow">
            <div class="profileheadtitle">
                <span class=" headline txtBlue size15">
                    Profession
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="profileheadcontent-narrow">
                <span class="txtGrey size15">
                    administration
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When displayed on the webpage it shows as "Profession administration". What I want to do is extract the profession, in this case "administration". However, it's not as simple as it might seem because this piece of code is repeated many times for various other questions, such as

```
        <div class="user-details-narrow">
            <div class="profileheadtitle">
                <span class=" headline txtBlue size15">
                    Industry
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="profileheadcontent-narrow">
                <span class="txtGrey size15">
                    banking
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas on a good solution?

Comment: What is unique about `administration`, I don't see anything different from `banking`.

Comment: There is nothing unique about either field, that's my problem.

Comment: Yes, I could see that being a problem. I can't think of a way programmatically to identify the correct one in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not use regular expressions for getting node values from a page.

PHP have a very nice class named [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php). You can just fetch a page as DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadURL("http://test.de/page.html");
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$spaner = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'size15')]");
echo $spaner->item(0)->nodeValue . "/" . $spaner->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Using PHP's DOM I still can't figure out how to parse the HTML correctly. As Chris said above, there is no difference in code between Profession and Industry, and there are many others too. How do I pull them all separately?